# Azure Function use same access token if not expired on succeeding Api call

Tags: c#, azure-functions, .net-6.0

I have an existing HTTP Trigger using C# that calls an external API.
To access the external API, I need to get an access token first.
I am using the client credentials flow.

To simplify

- GetAccessTokenFromExternalAPI
- PerformExternalAPICall

Now my concern, is that every time I call the HTTP Trigger it always generates a new access token.

I want to reuse the first generated access token until it expires and generate new ones once it expires.

Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using [MSAL.NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/entra/msal/dotnet/), there is an [in-memory token cache](https://learn.microsoft.com/entra/msal/dotnet/advanced/high-availability#use-the-token-cache) already but since you are getting the token from an API, you should implement a similar token cache in your function app code.

This would simply be a Dictionary object for example.

But note that as your function app scales out to multiple instances, each function app would have its own cache.

If this not ideal as well, you could further enhance your implementation to use a distributed cache like Redis to store the tokens across your function app isntances.

Here is [a sample for a distributed token cache](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-dotnet-advanced-token-cache/blob/master/1-Integrated-Cache/1-2-WebAPI-BgWorker/README.md) that you could refer to for the same.